# Migrating Datetime to DateTimeOffset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, datetimeoffset

The time has come in the application I am working on to migrate DateTime fields in SQL Server  to DateTimeOffset.

Was wondering if there were any automated tools in SQL Server that could help me with this so I don't need to script a bunch of alter table statements?

Answer (score 6):

There are no such tools in SQL Server itself, however there 3rd party tools, that wrap up management tasks of a DB and generate change scripts for you.

In absence of a third party tool, you can write a script that will generate change scripts for you.

Here is a sample script, that finds all columns of `datatime` type and generate script to change it to `DateTimeOffset` data type.

```
select 
OBJECT_NAME (a.object_id) as Table_Name
,a.name as Colimn_Name
,b.name as Old_Datatype
,'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_NAME (a.object_id) + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + a.name + ' DATETIMEOFFSET '   + 
CASE a.is_nullable
    when 1 then ' NULL '
    else ' NOT NULL '
END
from sys.columns  a
join sys.types b on a.user_type_id = b.user_type_id
join sys.tables c on a.object_id = c.object_id
where b.name = 'datetime'
and c.type = 'U'
```

Also you can use an undocumented `sp_msForEachTable` to execute code for each table in your database.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue.

Here is what I did to update the columns. I followed an example which I found online to convert the DateTime columns to DateTimeOffset.

For example for the NorthWind database you can do the following. First execute to create converting function

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_DSTOffset( @date1 DATETIMEOFFSET )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN
CASE WHEN ( ( @date1 > '2009-3-29 2:00' AND @date1 <= '2009-10-25 2:00' )
    OR ( @date1 > '2010-3-28 2:00' AND @date1 <= '2010-10-31 2:00' )
    OR ( @date1 > '2011-3-27 2:00' AND @date1 <= '2011-10-30 2:00' ) )
    THEN 60 -- offset in minutes
    ELSE 0
    END
END
GO
```

The try to alter the column by using this function - the example below shows how to do that for the Bi